# How to clean up mysql installation on centos

Tags: mysql, centos, vps, centos5, yum

mysql does not exist anymore but when i run `yum remove mysql` it says that the package is available but not marked for installation, i cannot install new mysql because of that, I need to completely delete everything related to it before installing new one, i do not have tables created so don't need to backup anything i tried to use the yum plugin yum-remove-with-leaves didn't work and didn't find any guide to install it properly, anyway i read on forums that it's buggy and should not be installed so I'm searching for other ways to remove mysql completely

and can i do it using sftp?

@quanta

the output of `rpm -qa | grep mysql` is

```
mysql55-libs-5.5.10-1.w5
libmysqlclientl5-5.0.77-1.1.w5
php-mysql-5.3.8-1.1.w5
```

**EDIT**

I tried

```
yum remove mysql
yum remove mysql-server
yum clean all
```

and it doesn't seem to fix it.

When I run `yum install mysql mysql-server` or `yum install mysql` or `yum install install mysql-server` i would get this

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `rpm -qa | grep mysql`?

Comment: @quanta please read my edit

Comment: What happens when you execute `yum install mysql-server`?

Comment: @quanta please read my edit sir

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`yum remove mysql55-libs` and try again.

Besides, I saw you used a lot of repos: atomic, dag, epel, rpmforge, livna, ..., it may be the cause of conflicting. In my opinion, `atomic` and (`rpmforge` or `epel`) are enough.

Comment: ok how to remove the repos that i don't need, 'yum remove dog' or is there another way?

Comment: Open the `/etc/yum.repos.d/*.repo` file and change `enabled=1` to `enabled=0`.

Comment: didn't work, i got a new vps and it's working now, i guess there was something wrong with the server, thanks for your time sir

Answer (score 17):

1. Execute the following command :

   ```
   # rpm -qa | grep mysql
   ```

   It will list all installed mysql packages on your system. Eg: `mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64`
2. now execute the command:

   ```
   # yum remove <name displayed in above step-1>
   ```

   Eg: `yum remove mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.x86_64`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    yum clean all
    yum install mysql
```

Comment: that doesn't seem to fix it

Answer (score 2):

you may have somehow installed mariadb when you thought it was installing mysql.

```
[root@localhost data_decrypt]# rpm -qa | grep maria
mariadb-server-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
mariadb-devel-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
mariadb-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: I erase above rpms with `yum remove` and run `yum install mysql-devel` again. And it works! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**this works like a charm on centos 7 if you are inside an air-gapped (offline) server and were installed mysql using rpm bundle**

```
service mysqld stop
```

```
rpm -qa | grep mysql | xargs -I % sh -c 'yum remove -y %'
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the packages:

```
sudo yum remove $(rpm -qa | grep mysql)
```

Then remove mysql dir:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
yum remove mysql*

find / -name mysql

rm -rf (all folders listed in find)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
rm -rf `find / -name mysql*`
```

This will find any files with mysql and remove them.  Once that is done, you should be able to re-install mysql-server.